# Specify field type in derived class

Tags: c#, field, derived-class

I have a Rectangle2d and a Rectangle3d deriving from it for backward compatibility reasons. In doing so, the type of the class' "transform" field shall change from Transform2d to Transform3d which is a derived version of Transform2d.
Here's a simplified example:

```
class Transform2
{
    protected float positionX;
    protected float positionY;
}

class Transform3 : Transform2
{
    protected float positionZ;
}


class Rectangle2d
{
    protected Transform2 transform;
}

class Rectangle3d : Rectangle2d
{
    // Does not work: Just hides Rectangle2d.transform
    protected new Transform3 transform;
}
```

One solution I do not prefer is going without a Transform class and direct fields instead:

```
class Rectangle2d
{
    protected float positionX;
    protected float positionY;
}

class Rectangle3d : Rectangle2d
{
    protected float positionZ;
}
```

In my eyes, when the second method works and the first method is just the second method with some bunching, there should be a clean solution for it. At least it hope so.

version: .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: your inheritance doesnt make much sense imo. A 3D transform/object is more general than a 2D... if you did it the other way youd have fewer problems (e.g. transform 2d is actually a transform 3d where z is fixed to zero etc)

Comment: Making `Rectangle3d` inherit from the 2d counterpart does not make sense - and that's your problem!

Comment: neither inheritance-relation makes sense here, neither is a 2D-shape a 3D-shape, nor is a 3D-shape a 3D-shape.

Comment: @HimBromBeere a 2D shape is a 3D shape with depth 0

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Just for understanding: In my application, I mostly use 2d objects. 3d objects are rare, but they are there. When I derive 2d from 3d objects, that makes more sense but I will also get a huge overhead that I want to prevent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance implies an `is-a` relationship. `Rectangle3d` is not 2d, so it should probably not inherit from `Rectangle2d`

That said, If you must do this I suggest you use generics

```
public abstract class Transform<T>
{
    protected T transform;
}

public class Rectangle2d : Transform<Transform2> {}
public class Rectangle3d : Transform<Transform3> {}
```

In this model both 2d and 3d have a property `transform` which is strongly typed.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is impossible, fields cannot be overriden. This is part of the reason why publicly visible (and `protected` is publicly visible) fields are diacouraged by design guidelines. You can abstract it into a property, though:

```
class Rectangle2d
{
    private Transform2d transform;

    protected virtual Transform2d Transform => transform;
} 

class Rectangle3d
{
    private Transform3d transform;

    protected override Transform2d Transform => transform;
}
```

Ideally your base class should rely as little as possible on the concrete `transform` field and instead use the `Transform` property. However, as a design suggestion, consider abstracting common behaviour into an `abstract` `RectangleBase` and have the 2D and 3D variants inherit from it, not from each other. You're on a path of creating a rather brittle base class out of `Rectangle2d` as is now.